# How to add extreme values to box plot in .net charting?

Tags: charts

I use .net Charting to generate a box plot chart. I'm able to draw the box and the median line. I even got the whiskers to work.

I use the following method to generate the `ElementCollection`:

```
ElementCollection GetElements(IDictionary<int, IList<double>> series)
{
    ElementCollection elements = new ElementCollection();

    foreach (int visitnr in series.Keys)
    {
        double perc25 = GetPercentile3(0.25, series[visitnr]);
        double perc50 = GetPercentile3(0.50, series[visitnr]);
        double perc75 = GetPercentile3(0.75, series[visitnr]);

        Element e = new Element();
        e.Name = visitnr.ToString();
        e.YValue = perc75;
        e.YValueStart = perc25;

        // median
        SubValue sv = SubValue.FromValue(perc50);
        sv.Line.Width = 2;
        sv.Line.Length = 21;
        sv.Type = SubValueType.Line;
        e.SubValues.Add(sv);

        // whiskers
        double maxWhiskerOffset = (perc75 - perc25) * 1.5;
        if (perc25 - maxWhiskerOffset < series[visitnr][0])
            e.ErrorLowValue = series[visitnr][0];
        else
            e.ErrorLowValue = perc25 - maxWhiskerOffset;
        if (perc75 + maxWhiskerOffset > series[visitnr][series[visitnr].Count - 1])
            e.ErrorHighValue = series[visitnr][series[visitnr].Count - 1];
        else
            e.ErrorHighValue = perc75 + maxWhiskerOffset;

        elements.Add(e);
    }

    return elements;
}
```

What I don't know: How can I add extreme values? I need to display values that are not inside the wiskers area. Lines or dots, whatever works. I tried to do this via additional elements, but that does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add sub values and give them a certain type:

```
SubValue ev = SubValue.FromValue(v);
ev.Type = SubValueType.Marker;

e.SubValues.Add(ev);
```